# Value of type '(params: any) => CSSProperties' has no properties in common with type 'Properties<string | number>'. Did you mean to call it?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

Why does this property in react CSS not work if it is of type CSSProperties? How can I get it to work with Properties<string | number> ?

```
export const fields: GridFieldsConfiguration[] = [
    {
            ...defaultColDefs,
            field: 'amInitials',
            displayNameRule: 'Asset Manager',
            flex: 1.1,
            minWidth: 75,
            cellStyle: (params: any): any => {
              getCellStyle(params, 'amInactive')
            }
    
      }
];

const isDisabledbStyle = {
  color: '#FF0000'
};

const getCellStyle = ((params: any, inactiveCol: string): CSSProperties => {
  console.log(params);
  if (params?.api?.getValue(inactiveCol, params.node) === true) {
    return isDisabledbStyle;
  } else { 
  return isDisabledbStyle;
  }
}
);
```

Here are the types. cellStyle comes from CSSProperties which is an extension of CSS.Properties<string | number>.

```
export interface GridFieldConfiguration extends FieldConfiguration {
    cellStyle?: CSSProperties;
}

    export interface CSSProperties extends CSS.Properties<string | number> {
    /**
     * The index signature was removed to enable closed typing for style
     * using CSSType. You're able to use type assertion or module augmentation
     * to add properties or an index signature of your own.
     *
     * For examples and more information, visit:
     * https://github.com/frenic/csstype#what-should-i-do-when-i-get-type-errors
     */
    }
```

Here is Properties

```
export interface Properties<TLength = string | 0> extends StandardProperties<TLength>, VendorProperties<TLength>, ObsoleteProperties<TLength>, SvgProperties<TLength> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are using [AG Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ag-grid), and trying to configure a `cellStyleFunc` for the [`cellStyle`](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/cell-styles/#cell-style) option of column definitions?

As shown in the linked documentation, it is indeed possible to provide a function that takes a `params` argument.

But it looks like in your case, you have an intermediate `GridFieldsConfiguration` *custom* type, that expects `cellStyle` to be of type `Properties<string | number>` (which is very probably actually [`React.CSSProperties`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0eab8010f41fbec067bd3cd2a1a45d56bac014f3/types/react/index.d.ts#L1576-L1585)), which does not accepts the function form, hence the error message.

If the rest of your code that handles `GridFieldsConfiguration` really expects `CSSProperties` and not the function form, then you would have to refactor it first, so that it can handle that form.

If all it does is to pass the `cellStyle` option to AG Grid, then you just need to improve the definition of `GridFieldsConfiguration` type. You can re-use the actual types grom AG Grid, e.g.:

```
import { AgGridColumnProps as ColDef } from "ag-grid-react";

export interface GridFieldsConfiguration {
    cellStyle?: ColDef["cellStyle"];
}
```

But note that `CSSProperties` is actually not type-compatible with `cellStyle`. To fix it, simply remove the return type assertion on your `getCellStyle` function. If you want to ensure that the returned objects still resembles a CSS object, you can use the new `satisfies` operator:

```
const isDisabledbStyle = {
    color: '#FF0000'
} satisfies CSSProperties;

const getCellStyle = (params: any, inactiveCol: string) => {
    return isDisabledbStyle;
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-H4AAz53OAzjkIjbIjzDToFR4AjEOwhsPm15WobeI4K22q9VwTUfcMu2IezTtWbiRRCHUHfXnS4N2S4G7poSd+1ariXYB6Fdq5o3RhgYC7psANWhclwCtcNnduE0feVXZuiggD0nByOMCg551M+5xtN4ZEJGpaxrg8aJrg66+nAOSkimCL-lACQRlGoHga2UEVBMExrpwQA)

Comment: I've shared the types now if you could help

Comment: CSS.Properties looks just like that with nothing inside of it. I've posted the Properties interface too now